# lambda in rails 4 with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Job, Category and JobCategory models in my rails application. I am using postgresql as the database. I have many-to-many relationship between my Job and Category models. I am using search box for displaying jobs which belongs to that category.I have used this in my Job model

```
scope :by_category, lambda{|category_id| where(Job.joins(:job_categories).where("'#{category_id}' = category_id)"))}
```

but, I am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in JobsController#index
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...categories"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE ('' = category_id)) ^ : SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "job_categories" ON "job_categories"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE ('' = category_id))
```

this is my search box :

```
<%= select_tag "by_category", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id , :name,params[:by_category),{:prompt=>"city",:class=>"form-control"}%>
```

Comment: post the error what you are getting

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in JobsController#index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code. At first, your code in the lambda should look something like this:

```
scope :by_category, lambda{ |category_id| joins(:job_categories).where("job_categories.category_id = ?", category_id))}
```

By using scope and lambda, you already are in the scope of class `Job` so you don't have to use it again. You tried to create another SQL query in the `where` statement of your code and also your code would be vulnerable on SQL injection.

In your select statement you missed one square bracket (params hash)

```
<%= select_tag "by_category", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, params[:by_category]),{ :prompt=>"city",:class=>"form-control" }%>
```